# How to make a multiple select required but not empty

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

I'm fairly new to knockoutjs, so there is a very good possibility this exists and I'm just not searching for the right thing.

I have a `<select>` element that can have multiple selections. On load, I want nothing to be selected, but I don't want to fire the validation at the user before they've even done anything. I can get the validation to fire if something is selected and unselected or a little 'none' button that empties the selected array. This is fine. My `<select>` looks like this:

```
<select multiple data-bind="options: PossibleValues, 
                            selectedOptions: SelectedValues,
                            validationCore: SelectedValues">
</select>
```

Like I said, if I explicitly empty the `SelectedValues`, then I get my client-side validation message. If I don't, then `isValid()` returns true and I don't see any messages.

So, how can I make the multiple select required and fail validation on submit if it is empty, but not highlight it as a problem on load?

**EDIT**

I tried to simplify my example for my question, but basically I have a ViewModel, which has a child ViewModel and that child has an object that is a `ko.observable()` and is also a ViewModel. It then has, get this, a child object that is a `ko.observableArray()` of ViewModels. This lowest level is where I'm attempting to see the validation errors (adding `{ deep: true }` only yells about being too deep). The problem is that the lowest level - let's call it `greatgrandchildVM` - returns true when I call `isValid()` despite very clearly not being valid. Looping through `greatgrandchildVM`'s array allows me to see that `errors()` has values in it.

Why are these not bubbling up and throwing `isValid()` to false? Obviously, I can hack together a for loop to iterate through my `greatgrandchildVM` array and do it myself, but I'm guessing there is a knockout way to do this and I'm just too new to know it yet.

Comment: Can you put a fiddle together?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common problem with select elements.

After you set the SelectedValues to empty do this:

```
SelectedValues.isModified(false);
```

That should fix it

Comment: The thing is, I don't want to explicity empty `SelectedValues`. I want it to know that it's empty and shouldn't be without doing `SelectedValues([]);`

Answer (score 0):

Try using [this syncModified extender](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/wiki/User-Contributed-Rules#propagate-forced-validation-and-reset).

> Propagate forced validation and reset
>
> If having a complex data structure, the use of ko.validation.group
>   with the deep:true can often be a major pain. On the other hand, the
>   complex data structure probably also includes arrays and objects that
>   needs to be validated.
>
> Note: This is an extender, not a validation rule.

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'optionsCaption' binding

```
<select multiple data-bind="options: PossibleValues, 
                        selectedOptions: SelectedValues,
                        validationCore: SelectedValues,
                        optionsCaption: 'emptyValueText'">
</select>
```

This gives adds an empty value which displays `emptyValueText` when no value is selected.

If no optionsCaption is specified, knockout just selects the first from your 
`PossibleValues`, which then goes on to validate the selection.

The optionsCaption can also be an observable, or just an empty string

Hope this helps